# Reducing timestamp length in PHP using hash

Tags: php, algorithm, hash

I have coded my own implementation that generate 36 character's length identifier, you could say my own UUID, it should be something like the following:

1. Current timestamp value padded with - till length 11
2. Random 4 characters Upper case, lower case and digit characters followed by -
3. Random 20 characters Upper case, lower case and digit characters

Also the database table's field that handles that ID, will be in bin collation to make its values case sensitive.

The result ID may be something like the following example:

```
1491681481-TI5b-7aCPMLK9a7MMLoSdhr5d
```

Here, the timestamp length is `10` and I want to decrease that length and replace the difference with `-`. I have tried to search for available hashing algorithms available in PHP:

```
foreach(hash_algos() as $alg){
        $h = hash($alg,1491681054);
        echo $alg."==>".$h."== Length ". strlen($h)."\n<br>";
    }
```

I found that there are some algorithms returns `8` characters length such as

1. adler32
2. crc32
3. crc32b
4. fnv132
5. fnv1a32

Those hashing algorithms is fine for me. However, I'm afraid of collision.

I need to know the probability of collision for those  algorithms **where** the source string is only a decimal number? In other words, does the input type or formating should reduce the collision probability for any one of those algorithms?

Comment: since timestamps are going to be a known factor, testing for collisions in code would not take much work

Comment: @nogad What do you mean? However, I'm not talking about the whole `ID` generated, in this topic I just meant by the hashed timestamp value.

Comment: @SaidbakR what kind of traffic are we talking here? Unless there are hundreds/thousands of requests made at approximately the same time, then you'll have to break it down to the nearest millisecond. If this is also db-related, then you could use an alternate method.

Comment: This seems like a lot of unnecessary work to save two bytes. Why can't you just use the timestamp? Or better, a native UUID?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Indeed I don't want to save two bytes, it should be remain as the same length `36` but I'd like to reshape the ID by reducing the length of the timestamp using hashing. PHP, I think, has not native UUID generator.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't mean the ID itself or its collision probabilities, I just focusing on the timestamp portion. In other words, I don't want two different IDs values has the same timestamp portion value when they are generated in different times.

Comment: There is a [PECL extension for UUID](https://pecl.php.net/package/uuid), and your database may have a native UUID type. If you want to reduce the length of the timestamp, you can just convert it to hex and you will not lose any uniqueness.

Comment: There is a section here on UUID collisions, but I'd read the whole thing, quite interesting: https://benramsey.com/blog/2016/04/ramsey-uuid/

Comment: @AlexHowansky the idea of casting the integer to hex is great!

Comment: Or you could even go a step further and convert it to a number in base X, where X is the number of valid characters, e.g. a-z, A-Z and 0-9 would give 62, obviously the bigger X the smaller the length of the number becomes. E.g. with base 70 you can easily express all numbers up to 11 digits with only 6 characters.

Comment: @maraca very great idea

Answer (score 1):

According to [maraca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460674/reducing-timestamp-length-in-php-using-hash#comment73978879_43460674) comment, I have made a simple implementation that convert the decimal value of the timestamp to number based on 62 i.e the sum of numbers, uppercase and lowercase of English alphabet as follows:

```
<?php

$stem = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

$old = 10; //original base -decimal-
$new = strlen($stem); //new base
$num = 1491681054; // decimal input
$out = '';
while($num > 0){
   $devide =  $num/$new ;    
   $result =  explode('.',$devide)[0]// could use floor();    
   $remind = $devide - $result;    
   $num = $result;
   $out = substr($stem,round($remind * $new),1).$out;
}

echo "<hr>";
echo $out;
// returns 1CWWnQ
```

By this way the the decimal number of length 10 is turned to a number of base 62 of length 6 characters only.
Change to the alphabet characters order, may lead to change the output result, also we may able to increase the base by adding more symbols. (but be ware if the id will be used in a URL)

[Reference](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/numDecToHex/)